# Tem como usar requisição Ajax em <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;'>

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Amigos tem como usar uma requisição em `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;'>`.

Eu tenho esse código abaixo funcionando,

```
if($buscasegura->execute() == '');
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; prod_carrinho2.php'>
                  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  alert(\"Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!!!\");</script>";
else:
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; cad_cliente.php'>
                  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  alert(\"Já existe uma conta cadastrada com esse E-mail!!!\");</script>";
endif;
```

e retornando para uma nova pagina, tanto com o sucesso do cadastro ou com a existência do E-mail cadastrado.

Eu gostaria que ele retornasse para dentro de uma determinada DIV, e tentei fazer da seguinte forma abaixo.

```
echo "<meta class='sucesso' http-equiv='refresh' content='0;'>
                      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                      alert(\"Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!!!\");</script>";
else:
        echo "<meta class='erro' http-equiv='refresh' content='0;'>
                      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                      alert(\"Já existe uma conta cadastrada com esse E-mail!!!\");</script>";
    endif;
}
?>

<script language="javascript">
////// Direciona o cliente para para suas compras, depois de executar o cadastro com sucesso //////
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sucesso').click(function(){
            $.ajax({url:"prod_carrinho2.php",success:function(data){
                $('#visual').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });


////// Direciona o cliente para inserir um outro endereço de E-mail //////
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.erro').click(function(){
            $.ajax({url:"cad_cliente.php",success:function(data){
                $('#visual').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tem como identificar uma `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;'>`, para fazer a requisição Ajax funcionar, ou não?

Answer (score 1):

O uso do `meta refresh` não é para isso, muito menos é um elemento clicável.

Também possui um erro de sintaxe nesta linha, onde o `;` deveria ser `:`:

```
if($buscasegura->execute() == '');
                                 ^
```

Isso não tem chance de dar certo porque o `meta refresh` com `content` igual a `0` ficará atualizando a página infinitas vezes.

Faça desta forma atribuindo à variável `$url` a página a ser requisitada pelo Ajax de acordo com o resultado do `if`:

```
<?php
if($buscasegura->execute() == ''):
   $url = 'prod_carrinho2.php';
   echo '<script>alert("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!!!");</script>';
else:
   $url = 'cad_cliente.php';
   echo '<script>alert("Já existe uma conta cadastrada com esse E-mail!!!");</script>';
endif;
?>
<?php if(isset($url)): ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo $url ?>",
      success:function(data){
         $('#visual').html(data);
      }
   });
});
</script>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Valeu Sam, obrigado pelas dicas, sou leigo e estou tentando aprender... Botarei em pratica sua orientação e corrigirei o erro mencionado... Mais uma vez OBRIGADÃO!!!